# Execute combine multiple linux commands in one line for different user

Tags: linux, bash

Is it possible to combine multiple linux commands for different users?
I mean, I'm logged on `root`. 
From `root` user I would like to log in on `jaworows` user and execute some command on `jaworows`.

`&&` seems not working, because it is executing only first command.

```
 root@jaworows:~# su jaworows && echo "hi"
 jaworows@jaworows:/root$
```

I would like to see "hi" when I log in on jaworows.

Answer (score 0):

`su jaworows` starts a new shell; the command does not complete until you exit that shell. At that point, if the shell exists with status 0, the `echo "hi"` will execute.